# Unable to send POST request to DialogFlow (404)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am working on upgrading a 3 year old api.ai app to DialogFlow. I have modified the request using the [Migration Guide](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide). I get a 404 error using the base url:
[https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{session=projects/Project_ID/agent/sessions/1}:detectIntent](https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/%7Bsession=projects/synccontroller-606c5/agent/sessions/1%7D:detectIntent)

This is from the [detectIntent documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent). I am trying to use the detectIntent method, but I was having the same problem when I tried to use context. Additionally, I have tried on multiple networks. I even get a 404 when I put it in a browser. Any idea what is incorrect in my URL?

Comment: Is that the exact URL you've used (replacing the Project_ID), with the braces and all?

Comment: @Prisoner, yes it is. The only part I changed was the Project_ID

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted at the [documentation for detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent), the URL uses [Google API HTTP notation](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto) to document parameters and how they need to be specified. That second link isn't very useful, but basically it means that you can interpret the URL

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}:detectIntent
```

as

- The parts outside the {} are literal. That is exactly what you should be sending in the URL.
- The {} is not literal. It specifies a parameter.
- The part inside the {} is a parameter named "session".
- The "session" parameter takes the form of a string that has two portions that can be a single path segment (the description of detectIntent puts additional limitations on these portions, but sometimes this is specified in the notation) and the rest is a literal path.

So if the session is `projects/12345/agent/sessions/6789` then the URL will be

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/12345/agent/sessions/6789:detectIntent
```

Comment: It is difficult to help without understanding what you've tried. I would suggest creating a new question, posting as much details about the problem and error as you can .

Comment: Your exact link example, of course configured with my data.

Comment: Did you read the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent and are using all the other values specified there? Otherwise, it isn't clear what you might be doing differently.

Comment: Again, without seeing what you're doing, I can't offer any further suggestions or insight.

Comment: https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/nameOfMyProject/agent/intents

Into the POST parameters I'm adding the "Authorization" parameter with the bearer token as value

Comment: Please post this as a new question, providing as much information as you can about what you're trying to do. Trying to do this through comments is exceptionally difficult since it doesn't show formatted information well.